# In "Chronicles of the Unhewn Throne" Trilogy, why did the gods take on human form?

Tags: the-unhewn-throne

I may have missed it, but I've no clue why they did it, and ended up making themselves vulnerable to the csestriim. Any ideas?

Comment: In Greek Mythology it was so they could score with Greek babes.

Answer (score 1):

Just read the whole series and I was wondering the same thing. The author did not seem to state explicitly WHY they inhabited the bodies but here are a few thought(s) with an attempt to avoid spoilers:

- Ego - Meshkent, especially, got a little full of himself and wanted a bigger portfolio
- Love - Ciena attempting to save her husband
- Hull - to fix things, the Kettral were tough but were a Csestriim tool
- Ego - Intarra, b/c she didn't want to be the sole Elder god hanging out on Olympus/Asgard/where-ever they were

Comment: You can post spoilers hidden in spoilers tag  [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72878/307083) ,without any hesitation unless the OP specifically requests no spoilers, if they are relevant or necessary for your answer.